# Android - two main activities

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

I build an app where the users need to sign in before they enter to my app.
When they open the app again I want that they will get the main activity (not the sign in activity).
Now, every user that enters, first sees the sign in for one second and then is moved to the main activity.
Is there a way that the user can first enter the main activity?

Comment: You will need a flag that tells the user if he's already signed up or not. For that you can use SharedPreferences to set your flag. Here's a simple example: [this way](https://medium.com/viithiisys/android-manage-user-session-using-shared-preferences-1187cb9c5cd8)

Answer (score 1):

In this case use **SharedPreferences**.

**Step 1:**

Add splashscreen Activity, which act as a welcome screen for the user.

**Step 2:**

In you splashscreen:

```
private SharedPreferences pref;
.....
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
pref = getSharedPreferences("your package name", MODE_PRIVATE);
if (pref.getBoolean("firstrun", true)) {
 

 //edit your shared preference in order not be true all the time
 pref.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).apply();
 //check if this is the first run 
 // start Sign in activity
 }
 else{
 //if not the first run, navigate to your mainactivity not sign in activity.
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming you have `MainActivity` and `LoginActivity`**

**In the `LoginActivity`:**

**In `onCreate()` check if the user logged in**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("LogIn", MODE_PRIVATE); 
String state = prefs.getString("state", "default");

if(state.equals("logged_in")){

//take directly to MainActivity because the user is logged in
startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class));

}else{

//do nothing the user didn't log in yet

}
```

**when you log in the user like after button click:**

```
//set a flag in shared prefrences that the user logged in before going to MainActivity

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("LogIn", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("state", "logged_in");
editor.apply();

//take the user to the MainActivity

startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class));



}
```